# TSQL: Possible to reference different database, depending on the environment?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

So we have the situation where we have two different databases and stored procedures need to reference the other database to get information.  We will typically write the query to look like this

```
select * from Mercury.dbo.MyTable a join Purchasing.dbo.OtherTable b on a.a = b.a
```

Which works fine for us in Production and our Development environment, but recently we split development into Dev/QA/ST and we have different versions of the databases to match the environments.

```
Example
Purchasing, PurchasingQA, PurchasingST
Mercury, MercuryQA, MercuryST
```

So now we are running into issues when we promote code because the stored procs in QA will reference a database for dev..

So my question is how can I change the database that is being accessed based on an environment variable?  I have started using DynSQL for this, but this leads to a lot of more difficult to maintain code.

Perhaps is there a way to create a "DB Alias" that is database wide?

Comment: Maybe these differences should be handled by the generation of your deployment scripts, rather than making the same code do different things in different environments.

Comment: This is one option that I was thinking about.  But the code isn't doing "different things" it is just referencing a different database.

Comment: Instead of using different database names to represent each environment, have you considered using consistent database names, but multiple instances if SQL Server?  This will still work even if you only have a single machine available as long as you create named instances..

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson Ill look into this idea.  I don't see why we can't do this, but I am not in charge of that aspect.

Comment: You could also create Mercury and Purchasing as new databases on the QA server that only have views that point to the tables on the MercuryQA and PurchasingQA databases.  That allows the code to continue to work, but doesn't force new database names.

Comment: @GilM I ended going up with your solution as it also allowed us to do a little more with deployment.  I would vote your answer, but it is only a comment.

Answer (score 4):

You can consider using [synonyms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx) for that purpose. In your case just create a synonym referencing other database table, for example:

CREATE SYNONYM MyTable FOR Mercury.dbo.MyTable

Each database will have its own synonyms, but the rest of scripts and stored procedures will be the same.

Comment: I went with what @GilM suggested because of our situation.  In the future we will have seperate servers for DEV/QA/Staging... so this shouldn't be an issue.